# What options do I have for reading Excel files and evaluating formulas in C#, Java and PHP?

Tags: java, c#, php, import-from-excel

I've seen various means of reading (and writing) Excel spreadsheets.  For example:

- In .Net as an ADO.Net source (as per [Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c));
- In Java with either [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) ("jxl") or Apache [POI](http://poi.apache.org/);
- In PHP with the Excel Spreadsheet Writer (as per [Format text in Excel file via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279917/format-text-in-excel-file-via-php) and [PHP:Writing to excel file using PEAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388816/phpwriting-to-excel-file-using-pear)).

But I'm interested in more than just reading/writing Excel files.  I want something where I can evaluate arbitrary Excel formulas.  So far in this vein I've seen:

- [C# Excel Interop](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084), although this seems to require that you have Excel running; and
- [POI-HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html): this formula support seems incomplete.

Are there better options or is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) is compatible enough with Excel that [Microsoft uses it](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/customers/microsoft.msn.money.asp) to calculate Excel based calculators on their MSN Money web site.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only targeting the windows platform, you really have no substitute for running Excel, and controlling it via a COM bridge.

As you are finding, any other solution is likely to be

- incomplete, and/or
- incompatible and/or
- inconsistent

with Excel.

Unfortunately, this does add a dependency on Excel to your software.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate Excel formulae, frankly Excel is the only reliable way to do this. So running Excel via a COM bridge is the way to go.

I've done this before in Java using [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) and that works very nicely. Excel looks after all the functionality. You just have to populate your spreadsheet (in memory) and let Excel do the rest.